# How to create a function that convert a dynamic Json to a formula in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to create a method that convert a dynamic Json that has this structure

```
export interface Regole {
    descrizioneRegola: string;
    naturaGiuridica: string;
    regolaPerCollegamento: RegolaPerCollegamento[];
    or?: OperatoreLogico;
    and?: OperatoreLogico;
    not?: OperatoreLogico;    
}

export interface OperatoreLogico {
    regolaPerCollegamento?: RegolaPerCollegamento[];
    or?: OperatoreLogico;
    and?: OperatoreLogico;
    not?: OperatoreLogico;
}

export interface RegolaPerCollegamento {
    tipoCollegamentoEsistente?: number;
    tipoCollegamento?: number;
    quantita?: string;
    minimo?: number;
    massimo?: number;
    esattamente?: number;
}
```

where the keys **"or", "and", "not"** can be dynamic.

For example I can have this Json in input

```
        let json: OperatoreLogico = {
          "or": {
            "and": {
              "regolaPerCollegamento": [
                {
                  "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 115,
                  "quantita": "NESSUNO"
                },
                {
                  "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 118,
                  "quantita": "NESSUNO"
                }
              ]
            },
            "or": {
              "regolaPerCollegamento": [
                {
                  "tipoCollegamento": 115,
                  "minimo": 1
                },
                {
                  "tipoCollegamento": 118,
                  "minimo": 1
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

and convert to this output:

```
({tipoCollegamentoEsistente: 115, quantita: "NESSUNO"} && {tipoCollegamentoEsistente: 118, quantita: "NESSUNO"}) || ({tipoCollegamento: 115, minimo: 1} || {tipoCollegamento: 115, minimo: 1})
```

as you can see the **"and"** operator in the above example needs to **'and'** the two objects in array, the inner **'or'** the two object in the array and the outer **'or'** to concatenate the results of the inner **'and'** and **'or'**.

I tried to create a recursive method but it seems that doesn't work

```
export function convertToRule(operatoreLogico: OperatoreLogico, initial?: OperatoreLogico, operator?: string, result?: string): string {
  const initialJson = { ...operatoreLogico };
  if (operatoreLogico.regolaPerCollegamento) {
    const regole = Array.isArray(operatoreLogico.regolaPerCollegamento)
      ? operatoreLogico.regolaPerCollegamento
      : [operatoreLogico.regolaPerCollegamento];

    const regoleString = regole.map((regola: any) => {
      const properties = Object.keys(regola).map((key) => {
        return `"${key}": ${JSON.stringify(regola[key])}`;
      }).join(', ');
      return `{ ${properties} }`;
    }).join(operator);

    let op = Object.keys(initial!)[0];

    if (op === 'and') {
      delete initial?.and;
      result = '(' + result + ' && ' + regoleString+ ')';
      convertToRule(initial!, undefined, undefined, result + regoleString);
    } else {
      delete initial?.or;
      result = '(' + result + ' || ' + regoleString + ')';
      convertToRule(initial!, undefined, undefined, result + regoleString);
    }

    return `( ${regoleString} )`;

  } else if (operatoreLogico.and) {

    const andRules = Array.isArray(operatoreLogico.and) ? operatoreLogico.and : [operatoreLogico.and];

    andRules.map((andRule) => {
      return convertToRule(andRule, initialJson, ' && ', result);
    })
    return '';

  } else if (operatoreLogico.or) {
    const orRules = Array.isArray(operatoreLogico.or) ? operatoreLogico.or : [operatoreLogico.or];

    orRules.map((orRule) => {
      return convertToRule(orRule, initialJson, ' || ', result);
    })
    return '';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're looking for:

```js
function compile(obj, op) {
    if (obj.regolaPerCollegamento)
        return obj.regolaPerCollegamento.map(p => JSON.stringify(p)).join(op)

    let res = []

    for (let [op, val] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (op === 'and')
            res.push(compile(val, ' && '))
        if (op === 'or')
            res.push(compile(val, ' || '))
        if (op === 'not')
            res.push('not ' + compile(val, ' '))
    }

    if (res.length === 1)
        return res[0]

    return '(' + res.join(op) + ')'
}

//

let json = {
    "or": {
        "and": {
            "regolaPerCollegamento": [
                {
                    "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 115,
                    "quantita": "NESSUNO"
                },
                {
                    "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 118,
                    "quantita": "NESSUNO"
                }
            ]
        },
        "or": {
            "regolaPerCollegamento": [
                {
                    "tipoCollegamento": 115,
                    "minimo": 1
                },
                {
                    "tipoCollegamento": 118,
                    "minimo": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

b = compile(json, ' ')
console.log(b)
```

That being said, this is a weird way to represent an AST, you might be better off with a structure like this:

```
interface Rule { 
whatever
}

interface Node
{
    op: string
    args: Array <Node | Rule>
}

//

let ast = {
    op: 'or',
    args: [
        {
            op: 'and',
            args: [
                { "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 115, "quantita": "NESSUNO" },
                { "tipoCollegamentoEsistente": 118, "quantita": "NESSUNO" }
            ]
        },
        {
            op: 'or',
            args: [
                { "tipoCollegamento": 115, "minimo": 1 },
                { "tipoCollegamento": 118, "minimo": 1 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: ok, yeah I know but I can't touch the source and BE unfortunatly. That said you function is perfect, just one thing.. I looked that the brackets are not correct. I expect that the && will be in a separate bracket, the inner || in a separate one

Comment: @travis_91: you can try to drop the `res.length === 1` and insert the braces anyways. Extra braces won't hurt much.

Comment: yeah sorry, what I mean is round brackets to will have this one (({"tipoCollegamentoEsistente":115,"quantita":"NESSUNO"} && {"tipoCollegamentoEsistente":118,"quantita":"NESSUNO"}) || ({"tipoCollegamento":115,"minimo":1} || {"tipoCollegamento":118,"minimo":1}))

Comment: ok I fixed. Thank you so much for the solution